# Find all list items via VBA

Tags: list, vba, ms-word, word-2007

I'm trying to set up a document for publishing to a website, so need to add some HTML tags before and after list items. However, it's not picking the list items up. Can anybody please help? Thanks.

```
    sub format_list()

            Dim para as Paragraph
            Dim is_list_item as Boolean

            is_list_item = False

            For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

                    If para.Range.ListFormat.ListType = WdListType.wdListBullet Then

                            is_list_item = True
                            para.Range.InsertBefore "<li>"
                            para.Range.InsertAfter "</li>"

                    End If

            Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: I noticed that `is_list_item` variable does not play any role in your code and hence is redundant, correct? Or, I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following instead of `para.Range.InsertAfter "</li>"`

```
para.Range.Select
Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
Selection.TypeText Text:="</li>"
```

Comment: Thanks @Zaider, but the issue is that it is not picking up that the paragraph is a list item (`para.Range.ListFormat.ListType = WdListType.wdListBullet`), so it's not even getting to the bit you mentioned.

Comment: How did you create your lists?  I created some by just clicking the Bullet option in the paragraph section of the Home tab and your code picks them up fine.  Try adding `Debug.Print para.Range.Text` under your For Each line and when it gives your list value check what the value of `If para.Range.ListFormat.ListType` is.

Comment: Turns out my code was changing the style to "Normal" before it got to this step, so that is why it wasn't working. As soon as that dawned on me, I made a change and it did indeed work! Thanks.